# Получаю разные ответы при одном и том же запросе

Tags: google-search

Почему я получаю 2 разных результата?

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Paris%20Hilton&cr=countryUS&lr=lang_en&hl=en`:

```
1- http://www.parishilton.com/
2- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Hilton
3- https://twitter.com/ParisHiltonhttps://twitter.com/ParisHilton
4- http://www.tmz.com/person/paris-hilton/
5- http://perezhilton.com/category/paris-hilton
```

`https://www.google.com/search?q=Paris+Hilton&cr=countryUS&lr=lang_en&hl=en`:

```
1- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Hilton
2- https://twitter.com/ParisHilton
3- http://www.parishilton.com/
4- http://www.tmz.com/person/paris-hilton/
5- http://perezhilton.com/category/paris-hilton
```

какие параметры ещё нужно указать, чтобы ответы были одинаковые, спасибо.

Comment: Персонализированный поиск у Вас случаем не влияет на результаты в браузере?

Также интересно, почему важен порядок?

Comment: результат тут другой, чем если просто https://www.google.com/search?q=Paris+Hilton.
Порядок важен, т.к. есть прожка, которая из этих 10 стр. посчитает приоритет каждой, выставит по рейтингу и сравнит с их порядком в гугле.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что я вижу в документации Google, данные API были упразднены ещё в ноябре 2010. Вместо них рекомендуется использовать [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Paris%20Hilton&userip=USERS-IP-ADDRESS

https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Paris%20Hilton&userip=USERS-IP-ADDRESS

эти запросы тоже дают разный порядок, можешь попробовать, я вообщет начинал с них, просто потом добавил атрибутов поиска.

Comment: Причём тут атрибуты поиска? https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web - упразднены 2.5 года. Они не поддерживаются и вряд ли даже Пейдж с Брином что-то подскажут ^_^. Проверяйте на новых API - https://developers.google.com/custom-search/